# Android GoogleMaps get location of Marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have implemented GoogleMaps into my application. What I am trying to do is show the users current location and then allow the user to add a marker anywhere else on the map. I have shown the users current location by setting setMyLocationEnabled to true. Then a marker is added wherever you click on the screen. I want to get the new lat/lng coordinates of the marker but it keeps giving me the coordinates of the users location. When I change setMyLocationEnabled to false and add a marker it returns the correct coordinates. So it seems as if I might have to write my own code to get the users current location instead of using setMyLocationEnabled. Any ideas? Below is my code

```
public class BasicMapDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMarkerDragListener, OnMapClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private String TAG = "TEST";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
        // map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                // setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LatLng position = marker.getPosition(); //
        Toast.makeText(
                BasicMapDemoActivity.this,
                "Lat " + position.latitude + " " + "Long " + position.longitude,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Creating a marker
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting the position for the marker
        markerOptions.position(point);

        // Setting the title for the marker.
        // This will be displayed on taping the marker
        markerOptions.title(point.latitude + " : " + point.longitude);

        // Clears the previously touched position
        mMap.clear();

        // Animating to the touched position
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));

        // Placing a marker on the touched position
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions).setDraggable(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: I dont understand the problem, `point` in `onMapClick` is your new marker position

Comment: Yes but point in map click just keeps on returning the value of the users current position instead of the new position where the marker is. Its very strange!

Comment: Try removing the map setup stuff from onCreate().  I don't think the map is ready yet, and maybe you're getting mixed signals by trying to set it up twice.  I had weird things happening when I tried to setup the map in a place other than onActivityCreated() or onResume().

Comment: Still not working I'm afraid

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear to me where the marker is coming from in the method you are trying to get it's location from, but it does not look like you are retaining a reference to the marker you want to report the position of.

When you call this method:

```
// Placing a marker on the touched position
mMap.addMarker(markerOptions).setDraggable(true);
```

it returns a reference to the marker that was added.  I think you need to hold the reference it returns and then query the location based on that reference.

So you could try something like this:

```
// Placing a marker on the touched position
Marker myMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions).setDraggable(true);
LatLng position = myMarker.getPosition(); //
Toast.makeText(
        BasicMapDemoActivity.this,
        "Lat " + position.latitude + " " + "Long " + position.longitude,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**First of all I don't see what in the posted code is triggering the call to the onMarkerDragEnd() event.  I don't see anything in the doc that says it would be triggered simply by adding a marker to the map.**  If you want to get the location from the maker added at the end of the onMapClick() method, then,  what I show above should do it.  While this should be the same as the point object being passed into the onMapClick() event, the question asked about the **position of the marker** that was added, not the point clicked, even tho in this case they should be the same.

Comment: This answer is absolute beauty deserved alot of 1+ Saved me alot of days.